# Cypress visit couldn't load

Tags: javascript, automation, proxy, cypress

I'm having this error in Cypress

[image]

This is my code

```
class MapsLocators {
constructor(){
    this.input = '[id = "searchboxinput"]';
    this.cityTitle = '[class = "DUwDvf fontHeadlineLarge"]';
    this.timeout = Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout');
}

searchPlace(place){
    cy.get(this.input).type(place + '{enter}');
}

validateCityTitle(title){
    cy.get(this.cityTitle, { timeout: this.timeout }).should('exist');
    cy.get(this.cityTitle).should('have.text', title);
}
}

describe('Google Maps automation', () => {

const mapsLocators = new MapsLocators();
const city = 'Tokio';

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.google.com.ar/maps/');
});

it('Go to Tokyo', () => {
    mapsLocators.searchPlace(city);
    mapsLocators.validateCityTitle(city);
});
});
```

This code works perfectly fine, it was running a couple of days ago, but we started to use a proxy server apart from the VPN we usually use at work, from that moment on, even we the proxy server disabled, I'm observing weird behaviors in my PC, for instance, EA app is not starting anymore, my Epic Games launcher did not work and now it is not loading my account config correctly.
All of this worked perfectly until I connected the proxy for the first time.
Do you know if this proxy can have something to do with my issue? Or it may be other thing, if I don't find the solution, I'll have to format my PC.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***Epic Games launcher did not work*** - it sounds like it's a systemic thing not a programming thing.

Comment: Indeed, its more general than a programming issue, but I'm using it as an example, I'm still having this problem in Cypress

Comment: The trouble is, this forum is for programming questions not connectivity issues (see the error message). It's kind of like asking "I forgot to start my web page server, how can I still test the web page".